# output of shell script in json form

Tags: json, bash

I want to get output of following small shell script in json form.

```
#!/bin/bash

 top -b -d1 -n1 | grep Cpu
```

Output:

```
Cpu(s):  6.2%us,  1.6%sy,  0.2%ni, 90.9%id,  1.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
```

Required Output:

```
{"Cpu": "6.3" }
```

How can I convert output of such every shell scripts in json form ?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: that's it? only `"Cpu""6.2%"`? I suggest you add an expecting output for that line in your question, so that you could get the right answer to your question.

Comment: do you want a bash script, say one or two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
echo "{\"Cpu\":\"`top -b -d1 -n1 | grep Cpu | cut -f3 -d " " | cut -f1 -d %`\"}"
```

A brief description: First, take a look at `man cut`, especially -f and -d arguments. The `\"`s are simply double quotations, which should be preceded with a backslash to avoid misunderstanding by shell interpreter. And at last, anything enclosed in back quotation marks `` would be executed, as described [here](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec08.html).

Comment: valid Json form is {"Cpu": "6.3" }, You are very near to desired output.

Comment: The script is updated. I've also added some descriptions so you know what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
your commands ...|awk  'BEGIN{FS="\\(s\\):\\s*";OFS="";q="\x22" }{$1=q$1q;sub(/%.*$/,"%",$2);$2=q$2q; print $1,$2}'
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  echo "Cpu(s):  6.2%us,  1.6%sy,  0.2%ni, 90.9%id,  1.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st"|awk  'BEGIN{FS="\\(s\\):\\s*";OFS="";q="\x22" }{$1=q$1q;sub(/%.*$/,"%",$2);$2=q$2q; print $1,$2}'
"Cpu""6.2%"
```

Comment: It's very near to output. it gives me "Cpu""  6.3%"

Comment: @K.KPatel the number is dynamic if you run `top`, it depends on your cpu load.